# speed up program execution [matlab]

Tags: matlab, complexity-theory

I want to run the following .m file in matlab:

```
function [relativeErrors] = plotRelativeErrors()

initialPrice = 115.47;
sigma = 1.34*10^(-2);
tau = 0;
days = 40;
Strike = 114;

Time = days/365;
[callSol, ~] = blsprice(initialPrice, Strike, tau, Time, sigma);

termOne = (tau - (sigma^2)/2)*days;
termTwo = sigma * sqrt(days);

relativeErrors = [];
for i = 1:8
    max = 0;
    N = 10^i;
    for n = 1:50
        v = intern_eurValue(Strike, initialPrice, days, N, termOne, termTwo);
        difference = abs(v-callSol);

        if difference > max
            max = difference;
        end
    end
    relativeErrors(end+1) = max;
end

end


function [value] = intern_eurValue(strike, price, days, N, termOne, termTwo)

prices = intern_simulateEndPrice(price, termOne, termTwo, days, N);
theMean = mean(prices);
value = theMean - strike;

if value < 0
    value = 0;
end

end


function [prices] = intern_simPrice(initialPrice, termOne, termTwo, days, N)

prices = [];

for i = 1:N
    termTwo = termTwo * normrnd(0,1);
    exponential = exp(termOne + termTwo);
    prices(end+1,1) = initialPrice * exponential;
end

end
```

The problem is that running this will take over a day, if not more to complete calculating. I had to call it quits after it was running for 14 hours and wasn't halfway done.  I have already tried to optimize runtime by delegating most of the computations that are static from `intern_simPrice` to `plotRelativeErrors` and passing the results through `termOne` and `termTwo`, but I barely notice any progression.

I don't think this can be reduced in terms of less computations, but perhaps it can be switched to something that would calculate faster.

Comment: You should describe your theoretical problem asking for an algorithm rather than expecting that someone tries understanding your code in a specific language and optimizes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** The following approaches will help you reach usable speeds, but will not reduce the [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), per se.

If your computation is slow, first thing to do is to use the profiler to find out what's slowing you down. In your case its `intern_simPrice` and especially millions of calls to `normrnd`.

### Fewer function calls:

It's usually a lot faster to let a function compute multiple values in one call.
So, first thing you should replace:

```
for i = 1:N
    termTwo = termTwo * normrnd(0,1);
    ....
end
```

with

```
X_norm = normrnd(0,1,1,N); % Generate N random values simultaneously
for i = 1:N
    termTwo = termTwo * X_norm(i);
    ....
end
```

### Preallocation:

If you know how long your arrays are going to be, it's also smarter to allocate them in advance.
So you should replace:

```
prices = []
for i = 1:N
    prices(end+1) = ...
```

with

```
prices = zeros(N,1);
for i = 1:N
    prices(i) = ...
```

### Vectorization:

Sometimes `for` loops can be replaced by a vectorized version.
In your case this would be:
Replacing the function `intern_simPrice` altogether and just using:

```
prices = initialPrice*exp(termOne + termTwo*cumprod(normrnd(0,1,N,1)));
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will keep that in mind. :)  Using X_norm = normrnd(0,1, [1 N]); did the trick for me; I expect the calculations to be done in 10 minutes.  With this, the for loop was no longer necessary as I was simply able to perform operations on X_norm and apply the result to `prices`.  This was not obvious to me at all though..  Technically the same operations are being performed.  The documentation for normrnd doesn't mention time complexity for its function calls.

Comment: This is a general approach in MATLAB. Most of the functions can be told to evaluate lots of values in one call. This way you can get rid of the overhead of function calls. Of course this won't change the time complexity, as `N*O(1) = O(N)`, but well, all we need are small constants!

Comment: You are (probably) improving the overall performance but you're doing nothing about time complexity.

Comment: @HAL9000: Yes, this is certainly true, I figured the OP wasn't using *time complexity* in its precise meaning, as there is also the sentence *"I don't think this can be reduced in terms of less computations"*, so I did interpret it as **Gimme more speed!**.